# Events not replayed when certificate expired azure iot hub edge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

**Context**

An azure iot hub with an edge device configured to have a cache of 20 hours through ttl setting in edgeHub deployment template. The storage is also binded to a host folder in the container options.

**Problems**

The last days, there were some problems in our deployment pipeline, so the edgeHub configuration maybe have been lost ? ( I hope not because, the portal showed that the modules just get stuck with the last working version ), and after pipeline problems have been resolved, the device certificate expired. So we rebooted the device to generate new certificate, the down time was approximately 20 hours.

**Question**

After checking the telemetry messages rooted to a blob storage, there are no messages in that down time, so why the events didn't get replayed ? and how to prevent that from happening another time ?

Comment: Hello, did you open a support ticket so Engineer could look at internal logs as well? Was this validated as Server Side outage? https://aka.ms/iothelp

Comment: @asergaz yes I opened a support ticket, but sadly, it took me time to get the support-bundle logs and they are not containing the events of service outage.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IoT Edge Offline capabilities, the IoT Edge device, its deployed modules, and any child devices **can operate indefinitely**.

Because storage of messages depends on the time to live (TTL) setting and the available disk space for storing the messages, you will need to find the correct balance in your environment to avoid losing messages when you cannot reach IoT Hub for periods longer than 20hours.

Suggestion then is to increase TTL. The maximum value is only limited by the maximum value of an integer variable, which is around 2 billion seconds.

Reference: [Understand extended offline capabilities for IoT Edge devices, modules, and child devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities?view=iotedge-2020-11)

Comment: yes, that's the first step I did, increased the ttl from 20 hours to 7 days. Another cool feature that a lot of messaging queues provide is the ability to replay events, which is in the IotEdge case not documented (or not implemented ?). Knowing that the RocksDB key-value database used for the cache system has still some .sst files present in the storage folder, it could be very useful if I can just replay the events..

Comment: IoT Edge uses Azure SQL Edge to store data. You can sync that missing data with Azure SQL Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/tutorial-sync-data-sync

Comment: I thought the cache storage is using RockDB, is Azure SQL Edge another database used by Iot Edge ? I checked the documentation you gave but it's plenty of things I am not necessarly ok with for my current issue, I just want to manually replay events, why is that so painful ?

Comment: In IoT Edge you can use [Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob?view=iotedge-2020-11) or [Azure SQL Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-edge%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fiot-edge%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=iotedge-2020-11). I never heard about RockDB being used in IoT Edge. Can you point me to that info? Sorry but replaying events is not built-in afaik. Advise you to add a new feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/0e2fff5d-f524-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0#).

Comment: Dude, I am talking about the offline capability, which is the case when network is poor or devices get disconnected, there's a built-in cache system that keeps the events in the edge and retries to send them when the connection comes back here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities?view=iotedge-2020-11

Comment: The storage used by default is a key-value database called RocksDB, which is not documented in Azure, but the storage folder contains files that show this database engine (.sst and .log files). Currently there's also some messages in microsoft forums that guided me to that conclusion. PS: I don't want to install anything I just want to use the already given tools.

Comment: I have synced with Product Team. RocksDB is a internal implementation details for edgeHub's messaging store. Nothing is documented regarding replay capability because it is not supported, neither is it on the roadmap. As I mentioned please file new feature request [here](https://aka.ms/iotedge-suggestion).

Comment: hahaha I hope that you're joking about that feature request website :D